# How to access properties inside an array and push them to a List Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, http, controller

I am working on an angularJS application, where i am accessing a service and getting a JSON data as follows.

```
    {  
       "repositoryFileDto":[  
          {   "aclNode":"false",
             "createdDate":"1433166794593",
             "fileSize":"16208",
             "folder":"false",
             "hidden":"false",
             "id":"d4850a7e-17f7-4ee6-a3c5-125c26077da8",
             "lastModifiedDate":"1433166794593",
             "locale":"en",
             "localePropertiesMapEntries":[  ],
             "locked":"false",
             "name":"accountInfo.prpt",
             "ownerType":"-1",
             "path":"/home/admin/accountInfo.prpt",
             "title":"accountInfo",
             "versionId":"1.0",
             "versioned":"true" },
          {  },
          {  }, 
          {  }
       ]

}
```

From the above array, i need to get the name property of each object and push them to a List.

Here is my code, but it says undefined is not a function.

```
 $scope.filteredDashboards = [];
 $scope.ExistingreportDetails = [];
 $scope.GetReportDetails = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://192.168.1.201/api/repo/files/%3Ahome%3Aadmin/children?showHidden=false&filter=*',
                // cache: $templateCache,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ='
                }
            }).
            success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.ExistingreportDetails = angular.toJson(data);
                $scope.filteredDashboards =$scope.ExistingreportDetails[0].repositoryFileDto ;
                console.log($scope.ExistingreportDetails);
                 $scope.filteredDashboards.forEach(function(entry) {
                 console.log(entry);
                 });
             $scope.ExistingreportDetails = $scope.ExistingreportDetails["1"].widgets;
    //alert("success");

            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                alert("Request failed");
            });
        };
```

I need an oput like this,

```
$scope.reports = 
 [
    {
        name: "AODdetails",
        title: "#f00"
    },
    {
        name: "AccountInfo",
        title: "#0f0"
    }
]
```

Comment: debug your code and try to identify the undefined function.

Comment: where is color and value field in your above json??

Comment: not color and value, its my mistake. actually name and title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this code on button click save function will be called and value will be stored in reports array.

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">


 <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

 <script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.data= {  
                 "repositoryFileDto":[  
                    {   "aclNode":"false",
                       "createdDate":"1433166794593",
                       "fileSize":"16208",
                       "folder":"false",
                       "hidden":"false",
                       "id":"d4850a7e-17f7-4ee6-a3c5-125c26077da8",
                       "lastModifiedDate":"1433166794593",
                       "locale":"en",
                       "localePropertiesMapEntries":[  ],
                       "locked":"false",
                       "name":"accountInfo.prpt",
                       "ownerType":"-1",
                       "path":"/home/admin/accountInfo.prpt",
                       "title":"accountInfo",
                       "versionId":"1.0",
                       "versioned":"true" },
                    {  "aclNode":"false",
                       "createdDate":"1433166794593",
                       "fileSize":"16208",
                       "folder":"false",
                       "hidden":"false",
                       "id":"d4850a7e-17f7-4ee6-a3c5-125c26077da8",
                       "lastModifiedDate":"1433166794593",
                       "locale":"en",
                       "localePropertiesMapEntries":[  ],
                       "locked":"false",
                       "name":"accountInfo1.prpt",
                       "ownerType":"-1",
                       "path":"/home/admin/accountInfo.prpt",
                       "title":"accountInfo",
                       "versionId":"1.0",
                       "versioned":"true"},
                    {  "aclNode":"false",
                       "createdDate":"1433166794593",
                       "fileSize":"16208",
                       "folder":"false",
                       "hidden":"false",
                       "id":"d4850a7e-17f7-4ee6-a3c5-125c26077da8",
                       "lastModifiedDate":"1433166794593",
                       "locale":"en",
                       "localePropertiesMapEntries":[  ],
                       "locked":"false",
                       "name":"accountInfo2.prpt",
                       "ownerType":"-1",
                       "path":"/home/admin/accountInfo.prpt",
                       "title":"accountInfo",
                       "versionId":"1.0",
                       "versioned":"true"}, 
                    { "aclNode":"false",
                       "createdDate":"1433166794593",
                       "fileSize":"16208",
                       "folder":"false",
                       "hidden":"false",
                       "id":"d4850a7e-17f7-4ee6-a3c5-125c26077da8",
                       "lastModifiedDate":"1433166794593",
                       "locale":"en",
                       "localePropertiesMapEntries":[  ],
                       "locked":"false",
                       "name":"accountInfo3.prpt",
                       "ownerType":"-1",
                       "path":"/home/admin/accountInfo.prpt",
                       "title":"accountInfo",
                       "versionId":"1.0",
                       "versioned":"true" }
                 ]

              };

              $scope.reports=[];

              $scope.save=function()
              {
                for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.repositoryFileDto.length; i++)
                   {
                      var obj1={};
                      obj1.name=$scope.data.repositoryFileDto[i].name;
                      obj1.title=$scope.data.repositoryFileDto[i].title;
                      $scope.reports.push(obj1);
                   } 

                   console.log($scope.reports);
              };


});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'repositoryFileDto' of undefined

Comment: then there is problem in your json may be some other name instead of repositoryFileDto check it. for me its working fine.

Comment: Thanks shreya, now its fine. is there a better way without running a for loop?

Comment: I am not sure without running any loop how you can access each object inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$scope.ExistingreportDetails` is an object, try this:

```
$scope.filteredDashboards = $scope.ExistingreportDetails.repositoryFileDto[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`repositoryFileDto` is an array, so:

```
$scope.filteredDashboards =$scope.ExistingreportDetails[0].repositoryFileDto[0] ;
```

EDIT:

```
$scope.filteredDashboards = $scope.ExistingreportDetails.repositoryFileDto[0];
```

To create a new array:

```
var newArray = $scope.filteredDashboards.map(function(el, id, arr){
      return //What you want;
   });
```

Comment: so `repositoryFileDto ` is undefined. Console log it, and show me result

Comment: console log what line?

Comment: console.log(repositoryFileDto);

Comment: its also undefined, i modified the question please check

Comment: It's not undefined just you have to use the key and the key here is repositoryFileDto so replace  0 by repositoryFileDto

Comment: I meant console.log($scope.ExistingreportDetails); so I can understand the structure of what you are receiving.@carton ExistingreportDetails['repositoryFileDto']?

Comment: the JSON i shared above is the console.log of $scope.ExistingreportDetails

Answer (score 0):

On what line you get the error?

You can use Angular's ForEach function to push objects or arrays. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

```
  angular.forEach(data.repositoryFileDto[0], function(value) {
    this.push(value);
  }, $scope.ExistingreportDetails);
```

You already return an json object from your HTTP request so there's no point in transforming into a json object here :

```
$scope.ExistingreportDetails = angular.toJson(data);
```

So if you want to output the value of "aclNode" you can just simply do

```
console.log(data.repositoryFileDto[0].aclNode);
```

Or if you assign you data result to the $scope.ExistingreportDetails :

```
console.log($scope.ExistingreportDetails.repositoryFileDto[0].aclNode);
```

Comment: thanks, this works, but i need to push those name and title properties and create a new array

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `angular.forEach()` method this way:

Try this:

```
success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.ExistingreportDetails = angular.toJson(data);

    console.log($scope.ExistingreportDetails);

    angular.forEach($scope.ExistingreportDetails, function(entry, i) {
         $scope.filteredDashboards.push(entry.name); // push the name from the object
    });

    $scope.ExistingreportDetails = $scope.ExistingreportDetails["1"].widgets;
    //alert("success");
})
```

Comment: am getting arrays with undefined